# Delivering EMC ISM by NETLAB+

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

I have made an EMC class with 15 students on NETLAB+. I have done the Pod cloning and assigned a single linked Pod to each student. But when students log into the class, everybody is connected, like they are using the same virtual machine. For example when they log in to windows, and somebody makes a new folder, it appears on everybody's desktop. Does anybody know what I can do to figure out this problem?

Comment: This might help http://www.netdevgroup.com/content/emc/documentation/NETLAB_EMC_ISM_Install_Guide.pdf